# how do i break multivalued attribute into different attributes

Tags: sql

for eg if i have an attribute named phone which always have 2 values. how do i create a new table with 2 attributes of phone no. and an attributed named personName

Comment: CREATE TABLE, with those 3 columns (at least, depending on primary key).

Comment: @jarlh i need select query for existing table containing multivalued attribute

Comment: Show us the table and type definitions, and your current select (the one that is not working properly.)